# Error while installing mendeley

Tags: command-line, bash, software-installation, mendeley

I want to install `mendeley`, but when I ran the command

```
sudo dpkg -i <path-to-download-package>
```

I got this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
```

Comment: what command did you run to get this error?

Comment: I use sudo dpkg -i <path-to-download-package>

Comment: Try running the same command with <path-to-download-package> enclosed in a pair of single quote characters.

Comment: run the command without the <>

Comment: but I got this massage "dpkg: error processing archive path-to-download-package (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 path-to-download-package"

Comment: I guess [the official instruction](https://www.mendeley.com/download-mendeley-desktop/ubuntu/instructions/) did not explain the obvious... You are *not* supposed to copy paste the command line as it is; Replace `<path-to-download-package>` with the actual file you have downloaded. Also, terminal must be opened at location where the DEB package was downloaded.

Comment: so, what I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the confusion here is related to the misunderstanding that **path-to-download-package** is figurative rather than literal. Assuming that your downloads are going to your default download directory you should be able to install with `dpkg -i ~/Downloads/mendeleydesktop_1.17.13-stable_amd64` where mendeleydesktop_1.17.13-stable_amd64 is the name of the file you downloaded. you can get the exact path/to/filename with the command `find ~/ -name *mendeleydesktop* | grep Downloads`

If this sounds too complicated you an simply issue the command `installpath=$(find ~/ -name *mendeleydesktop* | grep Downloads) && dpkg -i $installpath` which will set the environment variable installpath equal to the full path to the file found by the find command and then use that to tell dpkg what to install.